Sorting cyrillic and latin names and titles in bibliography
With reference to this question, I wonder why the sorting process only applies to names and not to titles.
Here a MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}

\DeclareSortTranslit{
  \translit[russian]{*}{russian}{bgn/pcgn-standard}%{setnames}
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{2021_Flor_Trudy,
address = {Сергиев Посад},
author = {Флоренский, П. А.},
keywords = {Florenskij},
langid = {russian},
publisher = {Таисии},
title = {Философские труды},
year = {2021}}
    
@book{2015_Flor_SullaSupEMiracolo, 
address = {Milano},
author = {Florenskij, P. A.},
editor = {Valentini, Natalino},
keywords = {Florenskij},
publisher = {SE},
title = {Sulla superstizione e il miracolo},
year = {2015}}

@book{2018_Trubatchev_PutKBogu, 
address = {Москва},
author = {иг. Андроник},
keywords = {Studi},
langid = {russian},
publisher = {Городец},
title = {Путь к Богу},
year = {2018}}

@inbook{1968_Motta_TEOSOFIA,
address = {Milano},
author = {Bigi, V.B.},
booktitle = {Enciclopedia Motta},
keywords = {Contesto},
pages = {7911},
publisher = {Motta},
title = {TEOSOFIA},
volume = {13},
year = {1968}}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Citing different authors \autocite{2015_Flor_SullaSupEMiracolo, 2021_Flor_Trudy, 2018_Trubatchev_PutKBogu, 1968_Motta_TEOSOFIA}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

In the command \translit I'm using the option * as indicated in the biblatex manual at page 236: «The field/set argument should be ‘*’ to apply transliteration to all fields».
The result is the following:

The last two entries should be flipped since the author is the same (Флоренский, П. А. = Florenskij, P.A.) but letter "Б" in the title "Богословские труды" is a "B", which comes before the "S" of the title "Sulla superstizione e il miracolo".

In BGN/PCGN transliteration Флоренский, П. А. is romanised as Florenskiy, P. A.. In particular the Й becomes Y and not J, so the transliteration of the name in 2021_Flor_Trudy is different from the form given in 2015_Flor_SullaSupEMiracolo, which means they don't sort the same.
Additionally, the sorting template the MWE uses is nyt, because we are dealing with an author-year style. That means that 2015_Flor_SullaSupEMiracolo will always sort before 2021_Flor_Trudy when the two have the same authors, because 2015 sorts before 2021. You'd have to switch to sorting=nty, to have a chance to get 2021_Flor_Trudy before 2015_Flor_SullaSupEMiracolo.
Finally, however, it seems you have hit the bug I just reported at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/477. The transliterated entry has subtly different sort key than the non-transliterated version. This could explain why they never sort as one.
